# Laravel 5 - using dynamic properties in view

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, dynamic-properties

I have a [dynamic property](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#dynamic-properties) `user` in my model:

```php
class Training extends Model
{
    ...

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

And I can easy get username in controller like this:

```php
Training::find(1)->user->name
```

But I don't know how to perform the same in view. I tried this:

Controller:

```php
return view('training/single', Training::find(1));
```

View:

```blade
{{ $user->name }};
```

but without success, I'm getting error `Undefined variable: user`. So it's look like I can't access dynamic property in view.

Any idea how can I use dynamic property in views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear that's not really possible. There's no way to set the `$this` context in your view to the model. You could convert the model into an array with `toArray()` but that would include the related model and you would have to access it with `$user['name']`.

I personally would just declare the user variable explicitly:

```
$training = Training::find(1);
return view('training/single', ['training' => $training, 'user' => $training->user]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't clear in my question. You can pass array of key value or object to view. So I passing object ``Training`` which has dynamic property ``user``. For example with code from question I can access ``user_id`` property, but can't access dynamic one ``user``.

Comment: Hmm. I fear that's not really possible. You could convert the model into an array but that would include the related model. Can't you just do `$training->user->name` in your view or pass user explicitly `['user' => Training::find(1)->user]`?

Comment: Yes, it seems impossible to use dynamic property in view. This code ``['training' => Training::find(1), 'user' => Training::find(1)->user]`` works as expected.

Comment: can you please edit your answer so I can accept it for further readers?

Comment: Answer edited. Also note that calling `find(1)` twice will run the same db query twice. Instead store it in a variable like in my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading)

```
return view('training/single', Training::with('user')->find(1));
```