# Laravel Error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am getting an error

**Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\proj\resources\views\mycases.blade.php)**

I have defined a relationship between two models Ccase and Hiring.

```
public function hirings()
{
    return $this -> hasMany('App\Hiring', 'case_ID')->orderBy('id','desc');
}
```

and paginating the results using a method below

```
public function getHiringsPaginateAttribute($perPage)
{
    return $this->hirings()->paginate($perPage);
}
```

The other model 'Hiring' has a method to define relationship with Ccase as follows:

```
public function ccase() 
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Ccase', 'id');  
    }
```

In my controller, I have following code:

```
if(isset($search_term))
{
    $search_term = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $search_term);
    $search_term = trim($search_term);
    if (strlen($search_term) > 0 && strlen(trim($search_term)) == 0)
        $search_term = NULL;

    $search_terms = explode(' ',$search_term);

    $fields = array('id', 'title', 'case');

    $hirings = $hirings->whereHas('ccase', function($q) use ($search_terms, $fields){
            foreach ($search_terms as $term)
            {
                foreach ($fields as $field)
                {
                   $q->orWhere($field, 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%');
                }

            }
    });

 }

$hirings = $hirings->getHiringsPaginateAttribute($results_per_page);
```

In mycases.blade.php, my code is

```
{{$hiring->ccase->id}}
```

This line is throwing the above said error while the output of `{{$hiring->ccase}}` is:

> {"id":1,"case":"HI this is a sample case i am putting just for test.","created_at":"2015-02-22 11:54:09","updated_at":"2015-02-22 11:54:09"}

What might be wrong with the code?

Comment: You're probably in a loop and at least one of the hirings doesn't have a ccase assigned.

Comment: My problem was with `public function ccase() 
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Ccase', 'id');  
    }`  and I should be like 
`public function ccase() { return $this->belongsTo('App\Ccase', 'case_ID', 'id'); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use related models in views. Here's the [detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29371005/1331425) why.

Your case can be solved by specifying the name of the associated column on the parent table:

```php
return $this->belongsTo('App\Ccase', 'ccaseId', 'id');
```

In model Hiring, it will be like

```
public function ccase() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Ccase', 'case_ID', 'id'); 
}
```

And now in view use it like this:

```blade
{{ $hiring->ccase->id }}
```

Comment: Thanks @limonte... I solved it by modifying the relation in Hiring 
 `public function ccase() 
 {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Ccase', 'case_ID', 'id');  
 }`
Is it a right approach?

Comment: @HassanSaqib why not, even better! I'll amend my answer acording to your comment

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but i think that you could use relations in view, you should use an [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) in controller where you are quering for $hirings, just add a:

```
with(['hirings.ccase'])
```

Could you please provide a peace of code from controller where you make a query to Hiring model for clear?